# Preprocess data for lstm in keras - Numpy, selecting every nth row loses me a dimension

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm, slice

I have an array y_test that looks the following:

```
print(y_test)

[[ 21.156  23.155]
 [ 20.64   22.976]
 [ 20.011  22.976]
 ...
 [-16.527  18.002]
 [-16.368  17.548]
 [-16.164  15.959]]
```

I want to select every 20th row, starting from 9, meaning position 9, 29, 49, etc.

I get the correct values by doing the following:

```
y_small = np.copy(y_test[9::20])

print(y_small)

[[-19.921  12.981]
 [ -3.975  19.921]
 [  8.916  18.529]
 ...
 [ 18.684   3.496]
 [ 21.719  18.855]
 [-19.637  20.749]]
```

However, if I feed my new y_small into a LSTM model I've been using I get the following error:

```
Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1081, 2)
```

This confuses me, as the inital array y_test gets taken by the system just fine.

Any help is appreciated!

edit: My problem was in preproccessing of y_test, but [Niv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69144650/7836972) does what I initally asked for. I'll leave this up as solved in case anyone ever stumbles upon it!

Comment: What's `y_test.shape`?

Comment: As I edited, the question is solved, I made a mistake in preproccessing, but thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, LSTM needs input in 3 dimensions. Reshape y_small NumPy array by adding a dimension.

You can reshape like this to achieve the desired number of dimensions:

```
y_small = np.reshape(y_small, (y_small.shape[0], 1, y_small.shape[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you! My problem was in preprocessing but this answer solves what I thought my inital problem was! I'll mark it and cose the question!